IP validation CIDR ReactJS
I have this function to validate an IP address with/without CIDR.
For IPv6 is the regex correct or maybe someone have a more performant regex to check IPv6?
/*
 * check ip address cidr  validation                                   
 */
function checkIpAddress(ip: string) {
  const cidr = ip.split(/[/]/);
  if ((cidr.length < 3)) {
    const cidrExist = cidr[1] !== undefined ? true : false;
    const cidrValue = parseInt(cidr[1])
    const partsV4 = cidr[0].split(/[.]/);
    const partsV6 = cidr[0].split(/[:]/);

    if (partsV4.length === 4) {
      // Check IPv4 parts
      for (const part of partsV4) {
        const num = parseInt(part);
        if (isNaN(num) || num < 0 || num > 255) {
          return false;
        }
      }
      if ((cidrExist) && ((isNaN(cidrValue)) || (cidrValue < 1) || (cidrValue > 32))) {
        return false;
      }
      return true;
    } else if ((partsV6.length > 2) && (partsV6.length <= 8)) {
      // Check IPv6 parts
      for (const part of partsV6) {
        if (!/^[0-9a-fA-F]{0,4}$/.test(part)) {
          return false;
        }
      }
      if ((cidrExist) && ((isNaN(cidrValue)) || (cidrValue < 1) || (cidrValue > 128))) {
        return false;
      }
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}


This answer has a regular expression that handles all the valid IPv6 text representations.
